# Invalid Parameter while trying to convert table image into BW and removing the grid in R

Tags: r, imagemagick, ocr, image-manipulation, data-extraction

I am trying to convert an image of a table  into black and white and remove the grids on R. When I run the command, output has message stating invalid parameter. Running subsequent commands gives errors because the earlier command did not get processed and the required modified file does not exist. How do I fix this !?

```
> convert_bw <- 'convert table.jpg -fill white -fuzz 20% +opaque "#000000" table_bw.jpg'
> system(convert_bw)
Invalid Parameter - -fill
[1] 4
> # remove grid
> remove_grid <- "convert table_bw.jpg -negate -define morphology:compose=darken -morphology Thinning 'Rectangle:1x80+0+0<' -negate table_wo_grid.jpg"
> system(remove_grid)
Invalid Parameter - -negate
[1] 4
> # read img and ocr
> data <- image_read("table_wo_grid.jpg") %>%
+   image_crop(geometry_area(0, 0, 80, 25)) %>%
+   image_ocr() %>%
+   stringi::stri_split(fixed = "\n")
Error in magick_image_readpath(path, density, depth, strip, defines) : 
  rsession.exe: UnableToOpenBlob `C:\Users\AP\Documents\table_wo_grid.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924
```

Answer (score 1):

In your system commands, use `magick convert` not just `convert`.

From imagemagick 7, `convert` is a legacy utility which needs to be installed separately, and on Windows (as you appear to be using), `convert` instead runs a tool to convert volumes from FAT to NTFS - not what you want, but explaining why you're getting the 'Invalid parameter' error.

Alternatively, consider using the R package [`magick`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) to avoid using `system()` and instead do everything from within R.